# Javascript Tic Tac Toe Computer Player Does Not Play Consistently

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, factory, tic-tac-toe, iife

I have created a tic tac toe game using javascript, which allows the user to play against the computer. The problem I am faced with is that the computer only plays some of the time when the user plays. This results in the board having disproportionately more player moves than computer moves and it also seems to not register a win whenever either X or O is in a row. I would like to eventually implement the min max function but must first overcome this problem. Someone please help! Please see the code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Tic-Tac-Toe</title>
        <script src="game.js" defer></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="layout.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header id="title">Tic-Tac-Toe</header>
        <main>
            <!--<div id="playerSelection">
                <p>Select Your Mark</p>
                <button id="x">X</button><button id="o">O</button>
            </div>-->
            <div id="board">
                <div id = "one" class="sector"></div>
                <div id = "two" class="sector"></div>
                <div id = "three" class="sector"></div>
                <div id = "four" class="sector"></div>
                <div id = "five" class="sector"></div>
                <div id = "six" class="sector"></div>
                <div id = "seven"class="sector"></div>
                <div id = "eight" class="sector"></div>
                <div id = "nine" class="sector"></div>
            </div>
            <button id="reset">Reset</button>            
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
#title{
    display:flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
#board{
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px;
    grid-template-rows: 100px 100px 100px;
    grid-gap:10px;
    background-color: darkblue;
    width:320px;
    height:320px;
}
.sector{
    background-color: cadetblue;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 50px;
}
#playerSelection{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}
main{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.sector.highlight{
    background-color: orangered;
}
.sector.gameover{
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Javascript

```
const gameBoard = (() =>{        
    const sectors = document.querySelectorAll(".sector");
    
    let sector = Array.from(sectors);
    
    const winner = [
        [0,1,2],
        [3,4,5],
        [6,7,8],
        [0,3,6],
        [1,4,7],
        [2,5,8],
        [0,4,8],
        [2,4,6]
    ];

    let choice = "O";
                    
    const Players = (humanPlayer)=>{
        const machine = () => {            
            let play = Math.floor(Math.random() * sector.length);
            if(sector[play].textContent === ""){
                sector[play].textContent = "X";
                console.log(play);
            }            
        }
        return{humanPlayer, machine}
    }
    
    const player = Players(choice);

    const gamePlay = () =>{
        const boardFull = () => sector.every((val) => val.textContent != "");
        const gameOver = () => sector.forEach((spot) =>{
            if(spot != choice){
                     spot.classList.add("gameover");
                       }
         })
        const move = () =>{            
            sector.forEach((mark)=>{                
                let step = ()=>{
                    if(mark.textContent === ""){                        
                    choice = choice === "O"?"X":"O";
                    mark.textContent = player.humanPlayer;
                    player.machine();                    
                    gameWinner();
                    }                                                                     
                }
                mark.addEventListener("click",step);
            })                
        }
        const resetGame = () =>{
            const reset = document.querySelector("#reset");
            reset.addEventListener('click',()=>{
                sector.forEach((mark) =>{
                    mark.classList.remove("highlight");
                    mark.classList.remove("gameover");
                    mark.textContent = "";
                })
            })
        }
         
        const highLight = (combo) => {
                combo.forEach((idx) => sector[idx].classList.add("highlight"))
        }          
        const gameWinner = () =>{
            let checkWinner = winner.find((combo)=>combo.every((idx) => sector[idx].textContent === choice));
            if(checkWinner){                    
                highLight(checkWinner);
                gameOver();
            }else if(boardFull()){
                alert("Tie!");
            }
        };
        
        move();
        resetGame();                        
    }    
    return {gamePlay};       
})();
gameBoard.gamePlay();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const machine = () => {            
  let play = Math.floor(Math.random() * sector.length);
    if(sector[play].textContent === ""){
      sector[play].textContent = "X";
      console.log(play);
    }            
}
```

In this block of code it looks like if the computer chooses a move where you have already moved, it just skips the move, instead of trying to pick a new move.

Solving this using a while loop, just be careful that you don't leave it with no legal moves (like in a tie), otherwise you have an infinite loop:

```
const machine = () => {            
  let play = Math.floor(Math.random() * sector.length);
  while(sector[play].textContent !== ""){
    play = Math.floor(Math.random() * sector.length);
  }
  sector[play].textContent = "X";
  console.log(play);        
}
```

Comment: Hi Travis. Thanks for responding. How would I get the computer to choose another move in this case then?

Comment: @Reemy876, You could do that with a while loop. So the logic would be "while play is not a blank tile, try a new random tile'.   That way it keeps trying random tiles until it finds a blank tile that it can play.  Editing my answer to include code...

Comment: Thank you for this Travis! I will try to modify this code and fix it so that there is no runtime error

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: The game hangs up on the last available move whenever the game is about to tie and whenever the human player has a win combo, it doesnt register until after another move is made.